# How do I keep my display output from toggling by itself?

Tags: debian, display-settings

It happens with a Vostro 3550, Debian, Gnome and a Philips 1080p television.

As soon as I connect the HDMI it starts toggling output and goes from mirror to just the laptop display to just the TV to conjugated at intervals of 15 seconds to 5 minutes.

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> command and the display tab change it, only for it to continue happening.

I should also mention that the TV shifts from 1080p and a more contrasted image with less quality throughout this toggling.

xrandr

```
>Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1366x768       60.0 +   40.1  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 640mm x 360mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     30.0     25.0     30.0     25.0     24.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1360x768       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0  
   1440x576       25.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1440x480       30.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

after

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1360x768 --output HDMI1 --same-as LVDS1

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0 +   40.1  
   1360x768       59.8*    60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 640mm x 360mm
   1920x1080      60.0 +   50.0     30.0     25.0     30.0     25.0     24.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1360x768       59.8* 
   1280x720       60.0     50.0  
   1440x576       25.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1440x480       30.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I tried stopping `udev` in case that was causing the toggling:

```
root@mach:/home/rt# sudo service udev stop
[ ok ] Stopping the hotplug events dispatcher: udevd.

root@mach:/home/rt# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   40.1  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 640mm x 360mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     30.0     25.0     30.0     25.0     24.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1360x768       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0  
   1440x576       25.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1440x480       30.0  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        60.0     59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Do you have an xorg.conf? If so, please post it. Does it work if you set it up using `xrandr`?

Comment: @terdon question has been edited

Comment: I was thinking about trying to manually set up the resolution with `xrandr`. Something like `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1360x768 --output HDMI1 --same-as LVDS1
`. If `xrand` makes the changes persistent, play around with it until you find the right mode and we can see about making it automatic. Thanks for deleting the cross-post by the way.

Comment: @terdon I must be honest and say that I don't know how xrandr works but I would definitely read whatever I could get given that this is keeping me from leaving windows.

Comment: @terdon looking at some wikis and I hope to be up to par to give it a shot.

Comment: Try the command I suggested, that just might work directly.

Comment: @terdon it was on the hdmi and after the command it set ot to mirrored.it now gives -see question

Comment: So it did set it to mirrored? That's what you want right? But it kept switching back and forth again?

Comment: @terdon and it just flickered

Comment: @terdon i need it to not toggle after being chosen either on the display window or via Fn F1

Comment: Yes, I was hoping setting a value explicitly with `xrandr` would stop the toggling. You never answered if you have an `/etc/xrog.conf` file. If you do, please add it to your question. I am pretty sure this toggling is being done by `udev`, what happens if you run `sudo service udev stop` and then the `xrand` command again?

Comment: @terdon this is gonna sound stupid but how do I check for the /etc/xrog.conf and give you the output?

Comment: Just run `ls /etx/X11/xorg.conf` (sorry, I had given you the wrong path before) if a file is there, you'll see it. In the meantime I have asked a mod to give you access to the chat room because this kind of thing is much easier to debug that way. I'll let you know if he replies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11277/discussion-between-terdon-and-survmach)

Comment: @terdon root@mach:/home/rt# ls /etx/X11/xorg.conf
ls: cannot access /etx/X11/xorg.conf: No such file or directory
root@mach:/home/rt#

Comment: @terdon I'm in the chat

Comment: @terdon Hey man, just to let you know that I found the best xrandr and that I tried to execute commands to delete the other possible configurations and to disable the driver altogether but the system kept refusing the commands both as user and root (I wonder if I am missing something). I can also assure that it happens with Debian/Fedora/Ubuntu/Mint. I would like to point out that everyone should BOYCOTT such drivers and manufacturers.